# Was there a Japanese equivalent of the Gestapo during WW2

Tags: world-war-two, japan, police

Colonial Japanese rule on occupied territories has been described as harsh as has been their treatment of prisoners of war. In some cases, this was not a fleeting occupation but one lasting years or decades (e.g., Korea, Taiwan, or Manchuria). Surely, not all of the people in these areas agreed with this treatment and there must have been measures to enforce Japanese laws. There are many parallels drawn with their allies in Nazi Germany. Was there a Japanese equivalent of the Gestapo (or Secret Police)? Did they operate in the Japanese home islands or only in colonial territories?

Comment: The [Kenpeitai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenpeitai) operated both at home and in the occupied territories.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, that would be the [Kenpeitai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenpeitai). It was a military police corps, founded in 1881. The kenpeitai had jurisdiction everywhere within the Japanese empire and their conquered territories.

Although it was a military police corps, everyone fell under their jurisdiction. Not just the military, civilians as well.

The naval equivalent was the [Tokkeitai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokubetsu_Keisatsutai). Both units acted uniformed and in plain clothes. They were both known for their very harsh and brutal treatment of their victims. Both units were disbanded in august 1945.

The kenpeitai was much larger and under control of the army. The tokkeitai was smaller, under control of the navy, but just as brutal. Both were used by the military governments as an instrument of terror on their own population.

*added: I think Ke**M**peitai, with an m, is correct. However, I don't speak Japanese. That's why I stick with Wikipedia's transcription of the name.*

Comment: It should be **Kempeitai** or **Kempei Tai**, not "Ke**n**peitai", i.e. M instead of N.  I can see Wikipedia has it as _N_, but almost all official documents in English refers to this unit with an _M_. For instance, Government of Singapore on their experience during **Japanese occupation of Malaya and Singapore, 1941-5**: [**link**](http://eresources.nlb.gov.sg/infopedia/articles/SIP_79_2005-02-02.html)

Comment: @JAsia it's the issue with Japanese romanization that ん in 憲兵隊 (けんぺいたい) can be read as either M or N...

Comment: @AndrewT. And it's usually transliterated as an 'n' because that's the perdominant pronunciation in most words.  Depending on the word though, there's usually one form that's 'correct', though in some cases the actual sound may be somewhere between 'n' and 'm'.

Comment: Which it is is largely systematic, depending on whether the following consonant is labial. But this is a stupid argument. Both written forms are used and there's no reason to chastize someone for using the form that's not the one you prefer.

Comment: N is the Hepburn romanisation of ん so I think this is good for consistency with any documents using that.

Comment: Before this gets out of hand, my comment above was not to chastise nor argue over the finer points of Japanese-English transliteration as I don't have the authority nor  talent to do so. Merely that OP of question was seeking the _name of the organisation_. Of course, Jos decides on the preferred naming but as this answer goes to the core of the question, I thought it helpful to indicate the name the _Kempei Police_ (by convention or tradition in official documents and historiography).

Comment: To clear up some confusion: ん was romanised to "m" instead of "n" (before m, b, and p) in original Hepburn romanisation but no other system. You may encounter this in historical documents but it is no longer the official romanisation. More info here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization#Syllabic_n